# All font families look the same in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, font-face, linux-mint

The fonts in all websites look the same, despite them being different in preferences. I also have the "Allow pages to choose their own fonts, instead of your selections above" box ticked.

For instance, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font_family_(HTML)  looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsXA5.png) for me.

Any ideas? Many thanks.

Comment: Maybe you could ask this on other StackExchange site, since this is not the place to ask this. Please visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

As the article text and table both state: what is displayed depends on what font files are installed through your computer's operating system (or in Web pages, installed as links to web font files). [image: Screenshot of the same Wikipedia page, taken on Android phone with only three installed fonts]